# PHP - how to get local time?

Tags: php

That's basically it, I need the server local time instead of GMT, so I need the offset (number of seconds) to add to what time() returns.

I also need this to work in any version of PHP 5, since I don't know if I'll have the latest version available.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could just use `date_default_timezone_set('...');` at the top of your page. (Where `...` is your time zone)

This will make all `date()` usage be set on that time zone.
For instance if you use `date("H:i d-M-Y")` it will show the time showed by Windows on your computer; if you had set that time zone to your local time zone.

See [PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php) for reference.

Comment: Cool. I also had your problem about a month ago - messed up my whole system until I found this.